# I get unexpected token while doing gulp watch

Tags: vue.js

this is my `app.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue';  
import Posts from './Components/Posts.vue';


new Vue({
    el : '.container',
    data : {

    },
    components : { Posts }
})
```

Posts.vue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    data : (){
        return{
            msg : 'Hello'
        }
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
        <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                <img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
                <span class="title">Title</span>
                <p>First Line <br>
                    Second Line
                </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
                <span class="title">Title</span>
                <p>First Line <br>
                    Second Line
                </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                <i class="material-icons circle green">insert_chart</i>
                <span class="title">Title</span>
                <p>First Line <br>
                    Second Line
                </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                <i class="material-icons circle red">play_arrow</i>
                <span class="title">Title</span>
                <p>First Line <br>
                    Second Line
                </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<style>

</style>
```

But i get Parse error : Browserify failed Unexpected token. near my script in my Posts.vue. I'm really confused with this. what's the error ? Same with if i remove my type="text/javascript". what's really wrong with this I' just try to display my data. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a syntax error in `Posts.vue`. Remove the colon in `data : (){`

```
data () {
    return{
        msg : 'Hello'
    }
}
```

Comment: Error still persists sir

Comment: Is the error message the same? Also are you using the official browserify template?

Comment: You can try the old syntax: `data: function () {`

Comment: I'm using it in laravel. So how do i know if i'm using the official browserify template. ?

Comment: I'm using vue 2.2.2 ? Is there any change ?

Comment: I mean this: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify And the error message looks like you have syntax error in your JavaScript. It's not related to vue.js